# GEODjango: select all objects that are contained in a POST request given polygon

Tags: django, geodjango, point-in-polygon

my request has coordinates that form a polygon.

```
plist = []
...
plist.append(fromstr('POINT(%s)' %(value)))
...
p = Polygon(plist)
```

using the GeoDjango I'd like to select all the objects (`places.objects.all()`) from a table that are contained in the polygon.

going over the documentation I'm finding ways how to verify if a single point intersect or is contained with the polygon (`p.mpoly.contains(pnt)`)but not something that works on a collection of points

is there a way to achieve that or should I use store procedure for that?

Answer (score 3):

I think the GeoQuerySet [within](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#within) filter is what you're looking for:

```
places.objects.filter(geom__within=p)
```

Assuming that `geom` is your geometry column.

Alternatively, you could use [contained](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#contained) but this only considers the polygon bounding box, which may be sufficient for you depending on your use case.